# How to modify the html output of a dynamically loaded script in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to take the output from the wordpress widget for Intense Debate and modify the html output that's returned. Though it's wordpress, all the widget is doing is returning a script tag. From what I've seen of how dynamically generated html works through a script tag, like

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.intensedebate.com/widgets/acctComment/12345/5'></script>
```

theirs is nothing special. It does this to call itself:

```
    for(var i=0; i<scripts.length; i++)
{
    if(scripts[i].src.indexOf('intensedebate.com/widgets/acctComment')>0)
    {
        if(scripts[i].defer)
        {
            if (window.addEventListener) 
            { 
                window.addEventListener("load", initIDWidget2, false); 
            } 
            else if (window.attachEvent) 
            {
                window.attachEvent('onload', initIDWidget2);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            document.write('<!--OMITTING HUGE HTML/JAVASCRIPT BLOCK-->');
            if ( typeof id_recent_comments_loaded == 'function' )
                id_recent_comments_loaded();
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

And also passes in the html it inserts in a variable. It does

```
parentObj.insertBefore(theDiv,theObj);
```

to insert the html (theDiv being the final html, theObj being the script tag.) I can totally understand the flow of how it works. What's stumping me is how I can change it after it does it's onload, or how to change the output before it displays. I'm not sure the variables would be addressable as it does it's onLoad. Any advice? I'm not seeing this exact issue on StackOverflow, so I had to ask.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using livequery (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) by listening to child elements being created in a parent element.

```
<div id="foo"></div>

$("#foo p").livequery(function() {
   console.log("added something"); 
});

$(function() {
   $("#foo").append($("<p>lol</p>"));
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mY8jx/6/)

Comment: I will look into this. Not sure how I'd match the script tag, but because it's a widget, it's got an ID set on the container around the script tag. Not sure if I'l have a flash when it updates though.